# C# Thread.Sleep(x) or while (DateTime.Now < dateStop)

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-sleep

We have a Win Services with need process a lot of Threads simultaneously and, each thread after complete, need hang-on for while before starting again (the time to hang on is on database configuration).

Everything is fine but in certain odd production environments some Threads has been sleeping for eternity with no occurrence of any kind of errors (Local log and Windows Events). The state of Thread is always in "WaitSleepJoin". The only way to get back is restarting the Services.

So, I did some change in our code:

```
Thread.Sleep(waitTime);
```

To:

```
protected void WaitTime(int millesecs)
    {

        var dateStop = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(millesecs);

        while (DateTime.Now < dateStop)
        {
            //Hang on
        }

    }
```

There is any way better than this??

Comment: Are you actually trying to do something like run this code every x minutes?

Comment: First, i agree with the first comment. That notwithstanding, are you really, really, really, really, really, really sure the thread is hanging in the WaitSleepJoin state while it is sleeping? It could also be the thread is blocked because of a Wait or Join (hence the name of this particular thread state...)

Comment: First answer: Yes, I need run codes every x times. But "x" can change due user configuration in database.

Comment: Second: I put all of threads in a list and start a new one just for check the state of all the Threads (logging into file). I had one Thread in the WaitSleepJoin for 2 days in row and no change either in logs or in database. Restarting the Win Service "solve" the problem.

Comment: Complementing: We had this service running at 6 clients (production servers) at the moment with different hardware. The problem in question occurs only in one client (win server 2008 R2). But this can grow to 100 different servers and I'm concerning with this "issue".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use events and set the timeout to be your interval.  This has the advantage of providing an option of a clean shutdown of the thread by setting the event.

You should not write the code the second way as the thread Wil be taking too much CPU.  Your problem is probably not caused by the sleep.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you have any sample of using events do to this??